# Laravel eloquent query model with pivot

Tags: laravel

I have a user model with pivot table role_user.

In my user table I have a field 'active'.

And a user can have multiple roles which are saved in pivot table.

How can I pull all the users where active = 1 and where user has specific role in pivot table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. This assumes you have an eloquent relationship set up between users and roles. I've only used this type of query in a `hasMany` / `belongsTo` relationship, but I think it'll work in your example as well.

```
$users = User::where('active', 1)->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('role', 'foo');
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you both for your answers, @jackel414 has a slightly cleaner code and it works but both answers are good!

Answer (score 3):

To filter users by role use `whereHas()` method:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($q) use ($role) {
    $q->where('role', $role);
})->where('active', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Is the `wherePivot` in this case filtering for active roles or users? I think it might be filtering for active roles, but OP is looking for active users. If this does filter the user table based on active though, this is a cleaner implementation than my answer.

Comment: @jackel414 I was sure `active` column is in pivot table. I've fixed the code. Thank you for mentioning it. ) I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, may I ask you to have a looko at a  Laravel table join related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions ?